# Lubuntu laptop with broken screen won’t show desktop screen on my external monitor

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, display, hdmi

I’ve been looking around for a fix for this and while other people have similar problems I think mine may be different enough to warrant another question, although I may have just been a little too dense to fix it with the other answers posted. My laptop screen is completely busted, so I need it to open up my main desktop on the external HDMI monitor I have. Weirdly, while grub doesn’t show up on the external monitor nor does my desktop, my BIOS and lock screen both show up no problem- it just shuts off as soon as I log in. I have already tried-

1. Keyboard toggle- works on windows, not on my version of Lubuntu apparently
2. Using Ctrl+Alt+F# to bring up a terminal screen. This does show up, although it doesn’t allow me to use xrandr to change my default monitor.
3. I also tried using the above terminal screen to dip into etc/default/grub and change the configure file to LINE_NAME = video=HDMI-1:D video=LVDS-1:d (I forgot the exact line name and what I entered in there, but it’s the line in grub.config that is under the one that says “quiet splash”, which I also tried editing to no avail).
4. I disconnected the LCD screen from my laptop entirely to try forcing the output to an external monitor, although I worry with that fix that I may have to crack open the shell to actually remove the wire from the computer itself, which I don’t necessarily trust myself to do at home.

I’ve also tried logging in and then opening terminal in my desktop through keyboard shortcuts to use xrandr where it potentially could access the displays but I don’t know if that failed for the same reason as the other attempt I made at it or because I’m just cripplingly bad at typing blind.
If anyone has an insight to something obvious I’m missing or doing wrong, or has a clever fix I haven’t tried yet, I’d appreciate it greatly!

Possibly relevant details:
I’m using a Lenovo Ideapad 110-15ISK

Edit: My Ubuntu release is 18.04.4 LTS

My external monitor is a Samsung tv, nothing special or weird about it

An odd thing my computer will sometimes do is that after the grub screen, I’ll get a wall of text and then it says something is up with the file system and I need to do a manual fsck (fsck /dev/sda2) and then it works again, it’s never caused a problem past having to remember that one command to get it to finish booting up but I honestly have no idea what could be relevant here

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting to me so quickly! My release is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I’ll edit my original question to put it in there as well

Comment: FYI: Your system is behind on upgraded packages (thus security fixes etc), https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ or http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  The installed stack may also help (ie. are you using the GA kernel & stack or HWE?  default is selected by ISO installed with, but can be changed post-install); why I asked for it first comment (ISO installed with tells me that). A `uname -r` will tell you the kernel, you'll see 4.15 for GA & 5.4 for HWE (*if you see 5.3 or an EOL kernel it's because you're behind on upgraded packages*)

Comment: I’ve got 5.4.0-42-generic when use uname -r, so HWE!

Comment: I'd also expect you're using 18.04.5 (`lsb_release -a` or `neofetch`); the 18.04.4 may have been your install media. Your point 2 is as expected; `xrandr` is a X11 program, text terminals won't be running within X so a message like "Can't open display" is what I'd expect.  I can't add more currently as my only lenovo laptops don't have external displays connected to *test* or *play* with.  Hopefully later.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time to help me out, I’ll keep an eye out for you! Edit: I used lsb_release -a and it said 18.04.4, I tried using just lsb_release and it told me that no lsb modules were available

Comment: FYI: LSB refers to *linux standard base*; very few of us actually use it (created by IBM for mainframes & larger systems than our little boxes), so the "*No modules*" is expected (as I took a lenovo ideapad as a small device, not s390 mainframe; we're not using it, why add them just to waste memory, disk space etc  Can't explain the 18.04.4; maybe check your mirror as being *up-to-date* https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  *You can find me & other team members at Lubuntu's discourse, IRC etc too*